# Composer script to start a background process, whose lifetime is bound to that of the Composer script

Tags: composer-php, phpunit, command-line-interface

I've started experimenting with [Composer Scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md).

I have a project where there are "Functional tests" of the API endpoints. Running the whole test suite requires running the following commands in order:

1. `composer install` to install all required dependencies of the backend APIs
2. `php yii server --test` to start a lite server that is connected to the "test" MySQL database. The test server starts running on `localhost:9000`.
3. `sh vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration tests/functional/phpunit.xml` to run th actual tests. This last command triggers the execution of all test cases, most of which execute HTTP calls to the lite server, launched at step 2.

I would like to automate and "atomize" this 3 step process into a single Composer script that can be easily started, killed and restarted effortlessly.

Here's my current progress:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test-functional": [
      "@composer install",
      "php yii server --test",
      "sh vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration tests/functional/phpunit.xml"
    ]
  }
```

The problem is that the 2-nd command (`php yii server --test`) "steals" the terminal because PHPs built-in lite server requires the terminal to be open while the command is running. Killing the command kills the lite server as well. I tried suffixing the second step of the script with `&` which generally makes processes go in the background and not steal the terminal, but it seems this trick doesn't work for Composer Scripts. Any other workaround or possibility that I'm missing?

My final goal is to make the 3 steps execute in an atomic way, output the results of the tests and end the command, cleaning up everything (including killing the lite server, launched in step 2).